# How to custom validate two text boxes with a regular expression /^[1-9]\d*$/?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-validation, angular-validator

I'm trying to write a custom validator for 2 text boxes, with some conditions.

Please see the code I wrote in [Stackblitz Link to validate the text boxes with some conditions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-rj2edg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2F_helpers%2Fmust-match.validator.ts)

Kindly help me where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that in `textbox1` and `textBox2` controls validators

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    textbox1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[1-9]\d*$/"]],
    textbox2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[1-9]\d*$/"]],
  }
];
```

Now remove the validator from the `formGroup`, `Validators.pattern` will make sure to apply validation on both the field.

Now add `errors.pattern` inside `*ngIf` condition to see whether that pattern matched or not.

```
<div *ngIf="f.textbox1.errors.pattern">should not start with 0</div>
...
<div *ngIf="f.textbox2.errors.pattern">should not start with 0</div>
```

[**Updated Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form)

Comment: yeah but the condition  text box1=1 && text box2 =0 || text box1=0 && text box2 =1  condition should satisfy. I'm trying to achieve this condition code in stackblitz.

Comment: looking at stackblitz now

Comment: @jhansiReddy may I know what is `widthFt` and `widthIn`? I don't see this fields in the form

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-rj2edg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2F_helpers%2Fmust-match.validator.ts. I changed them

Comment: @jhansiReddy take a look at the updated answer

Comment: @PankajParkar.tqs for replying me trying to help me. but when I make changes to your code , it is not showing any error for fullName.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-vickr2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247110/discussion-between-jhansireddy-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: It works, please check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-wju5ku), there was an issue because of `invalid-feedback` CSS class, it uses `display: none`